# Copy drivers from one ubuntu to another ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, drivers, dkms

Is there any way so that drivers installed in one Ubuntu device be installed in  another device . Some type of transfer of drivers

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it is not advisable. In order for this to work, both Ubuntu installs would have to have exactly the same kernel version, and same architecture (x86 32-bit or 64-bit). You would have to identify the installed .ko module files that are used by the driver, and any other scripts installed by the driver, and manually copy them across. Unless you are an expert you will probably spend more time figuring this out than just installing the driver properly. And you are likely to run in to problems updating - the kernel module packaging system (DKMS) automatically rebuilds modules when the kernel is updated. Unless your system is aware of the copied driver, it will not be rebuilt when your kernel is updated, and so will stop working.

Comment: couldn't he just use dpkg-repack on the drivers he wants?

Comment: @sbergeron Maybe, if the driver were originally installed from a Debian package, and that single package includes all firmware blobs (but if that is the case, then why not just use the original package?) A problem may be that many Linux drivers consist of two packages - one driver, one for downloading and extracting firmware, and dpkg-repack will not package the firmware blob since it is downloaded at install time, and so does not get included in the package file list. I would advise a Linux beginner to stick to the normal (simple and tested) way of installing and updating drivers.